# How do you make superlatives from compound adjectives like 'long-running'?

Tags: word-request, word-formation

Is it 'the longest-running' or 'the most long-running'? There are words with, I'm not sure what is the scientific term, an "inner" flexion in English (for example, 'passers-by'). Is the superlative of the adjective 'long-running' one of such words (actually, it's a suffix but a "form-formating" one, in that respect it's similar to a flexion, but it's not the point of this question)?

Comment: The term "longest-running" is not incorrect. Google's [NGram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=longest-running&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Clongest%20-%20running%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blongest%20-%20running%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLongest%20-%20running%3B%2Cc0) shows that "longest-running" is more frequently used than "most long-running."

Comment: @WeatherVane So?

Comment: What are you asking? I have answered the title question, it is "longest-running."

Comment: @WeatherVane You said, "This option is incorrect but more common". No wonder I'm confused

Comment: I didn't say anything was incorrect.

Comment: @WeatherVane Either you edited your comment or that double negation confused me a bit (I guess it's the latter). Ok, got it

Comment: @WeatherVane What about 'the most long-running' from the standpoint of grammar?

Comment: Sorry, you can see that my first comment has not been edited. I didn't want to say that one of them is right, but neither is wrong.

Comment: as a native BrE speaker I would use '*longest-running*' to mean something that has been running the longest time - longer than others.